# Reference problem, extending strings in mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a classlibrary where I have extended string with some functions that returns email and url links and so on. And I have this in web.config

```
<add namespace="TestProject.Helpers" />
```

Do I have to add "using TestProject.Helpers;" everywhere? or is it some trick to make it global in project? add namespace in web.config doesnt seem to do the trick.

/Lasse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code files you will still have to add that namespace with "using namespace"
That web.config node you added IMO is for views.